# How to have every pull requests create a temporary Azure kubernetes environment?

Tags: kubernetes, aks

We have requirement to have container deployed for every pull request and should have the URI for each and then should be deleted post Merge request is submitted. 
I am thinking of having dynamic namespace based on each pull request with the pod deployed and ingress configured to have specific URL without disturbing the existing domain URL and this is could be shared for development team.

Post verification and once they plan for merge request, entire namespace has to be removed.

Can you suggest the best approach to setup this environment.

Currently we have AKS +Jenkins+ Git Lab environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using GitLab, then the [built-in review app support](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/review_apps/#review-apps) will do exactly what you described